# UWP: Kiosk (assigned access) mode dispatcher

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, dispatcher, kiosk-mode

I tried to use dispatcher in Assigned Access mode. According to [Microsoft best pratice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx), I should use `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().Dispatcher`. But for some reason, calling `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()` throws exception

> Element not found

Any idea?

Thanks!

**Update**

I've tried to to put `LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView()` in my common DLL and it also fails with error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

But `LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView()` works fine in `OnLaunched()`.

Perhaps calling `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()` can't be done in common DLL?

Comment: Could you please tell us your OS version? Where did you call this method? This API should work normally

Comment: @Franklin, I am using Windows 10. My universal target version is **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)**. I call it from on of my common DLL. I do some further debugging and also noticed that (LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView() != null) throws exception, but works fine at OnLaunched()? Perhaps this function can't be called inside a DLL?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT I'm getting this same error. Will post a new question in case its a new or similar issue and link it here.

Comment: @Sam Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Felix, I did not find a solution for this. But my workaround is to allow my service class to request dispatcher through event handler. The event will be captured by the Framework GUI element and return its dispatcher. I know it is not pretty, but it is the only way I can think off until there is a better solution.